# Can an auxiliary verb (i.e. "has") be used outside a verb phrase, with the same meaning?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, verb-phrases

Lets use the word "has" as an example. We can say "he has done his work", where "has" is an auxililary verb for the main verb "done". There is also another way to use has, which shows ownership: "he has a pen". Is there any situation where one can/should use the first meaning of "has" as shown above, but not in conjunction with a main verb i.e. outside a verb phrase? Or does it not make any sense to use it except in a verb phrase?

Comment: Only in a deleted construction, as an echo: possibly corrective, possibly endorsive. (A) "He's not done his homework."  (B) "_Yes_ he has!" (more usual in the UK) //  (A) "He's done us proud this time. He really has." // (A) "He's done us proud this time."  (B) "Yes he has."

Comment: When *have* is an "auxiliary," it has no meaning, so it would be pretty hard to imagine it standing alone (except in the case of @EdwinAshworth's examples). You can separate it from its main verb in questions (*Has he done his work?*) and subjunctive inversion (*Had he done his work, he would have been paid.*)

Comment: It's a verb, so it will always be a verb phrase whatever its function.